# Date format not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime

Im submitting a form that has a date range picker in it.

I have the code to get the value of the picker from the form, which is in this format:

```
01/03/2017 - 01/03/2017
```

I also have it so that it splits the date range into two variables.

```
$one = 20/01/2017
$two = 13/03/2017
```

Im now trying to format the date of these variables into the one that MYSQL uses.

My problem is that the end date will fail and be displayed as 1970-01-01 all the time.

```
// Get the range from the form
$daterange = $_POST["daterange"];

// Split the range into a start and end date
list($one, $two) = explode("-", "$daterange", 2);

// Test the split worked
echo $one;
echo $two;

// Format the start date into MySQL style
$StartDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($one));

// Test date
echo $StartDate;

// Format the end date into MySQL style
$EndDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($two));

//Test date
echo $EndDate;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$one = '20/01/2017';
$one = str_replace('/', '-', $one);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($one));
```

// Output: 2017-01-20

[Working Code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ed4ee98bc07fa6fe00a4c1b831f887b89436c22f)

> For the reason, see [The PHP Manual for `strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) Specifically this note
>
> **Note:**
>   Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Comment: Thanks. I will make as correct when it allows me to.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: thanks for the update, because I know the solution but not the reason why this happens :)

Answer (score 3):

Personnaly, I prefer the `date_create_from_format` that does not presume anything.

One-liner :

```
$StartDate = date_create_from_format( "d/m/Y" , $one )->format("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to format your date:

```
$StartDate = date_format(date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $one), 'Y-m-d');
```

To reverse:

```
$reverse = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($StartDate));
```